# Platform-independent script for automatically identifying executables in system path for Emacs

Tags: emacs

does anybody know a platform-independent way for Emacs to locate executables in the system path? After googling for a while, I could not really find a universal solution that works for MacOS, Windows and Linux.

Ideally, I would like to have an emacs-lisp script/package  that locates some binaries automatically (e.g., browser executables).

If there is no general solution, I will try to write a script/package by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`executable-find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Locating-Files.html) is a compiled Lisp function in [`files.el`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/files.el).

```
(executable-find COMMAND)
```

Search for *COMMAND* in [`exec-path`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Subprocess-Creation.html) and return the absolute file name.
Return `nil` if *COMMAND* is not found anywhere in [`exec-path`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Subprocess-Creation.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a package that does this.  It's not hard though.

```
;; default is "chromium"
(catch 'break
  (dolist  (e '("google-chrome-beta" "google-chrome" "google-chrome-stable"))
    (when (executable-find e)
      (setq browse-url-chromium-program e)
      (throw 'break t))))
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-chromium
      browse-url-new-window-flag t)
```